# Find linked list group inside other linked list group

Tags: java

i have this class:

```
public class IntNode {
private int _value;
private IntNode _next;
public IntNode(int val, IntNode n) {
_value = val;
_next = n;
}
public int getValue() {
return _value;
}
public IntNode getNext() {
return _next;
}
public void setValue(int v) {
_value = v;
}
public void setNext(IntNode node) {
_next = node;
}
}
```

and this:

```
public class IntList {
private IntNode _head;
public IntList( ) {
_head = null;
}
public IntList (IntNode node) {
_head = node;
}
. . . // methods
}
```

This list represent whole number.
in this list there is no duplicate number, every number appears only once.

i need to add function `public boolean isSubset (IntList other)` that return true if the group is sub-group of the list or false otherwise.
for example:

A = {1, 4 ,2, 8}

B = [4, 8}

so `A.isSubset(B)` return true and `B.isSubset(A)` return false.
this function need to be as efficient as possible.

i know i can check every number from the group who received as parameter and search for this number inside the other list and again check the next number and loop again over the whole list but it will be O(n²) so it wont be so efficient.
maybe some other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to sort your lists by the qicksort algorithm and then search the elements by the binary search.

Here you can look at the corresponding wikipedia topics:

[Wiki - Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

[Wiki - Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: Sort linked list will cost nlogn, so sort my 2 lists will cost also nlogn ?, Binary Search cost logn so what is the complexity  of all ?

Comment: Average performance of the quicksort is O(n log n). So you will have a performance to sort the first of your list with O(n log n).
With the binary search you have a average perfomance with O(log n) to search an element in the list. You have m elements in your second list, so you have here a performance of m*O(log n).

I think this should be the result -> O(n1 log n1) + n2*O(log n1)    
 --> n1 = Amount of elements from the first list; n2 = amount if elements from the second list.